# How to set a model for function params in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, arguments, native

How do I set a certain "definition/model" for params that my function receives when called?

For example, I want function `f()` arguments to be a array with objects inside, and return an error if something that isn't an array with objects inside is passed as arguments.

If it is not possible, I would like to know if there is anything like setting some "parameter expectation" like those you see while typing a native function in VS code:
[image: It shows what argument you are typing at the moment and what it should be.]

It shows what argument you are typing at the moment and what type it should be.

To be honest, I don't know if that is possible, that's why I'm seeking for help here first.

Comment: Are you using jsdoc or making sure your types/interfaces are set?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? Why's this question tagged with TypeScript? TypeScript does have what you are looking for...